# Why is my Mac Mini slowing down? (HD, processor, memory, network, are all fine)

Tags: macos, mac, performance

I have a late 2012 Mac Mini with 16GBs of RAM (of which I use maybe 4 GBs), a 1 TB HD that is not even half full (and which I have verified to be working according to more [than](https://superuser.com/a/413307/8784) [one](https://superuser.com/questions/372038/why-has-my-mac-become-so-slow-and-how-do-i-start-to-answer-that) [method](http://www.switchingtomac.com/tutorials/keep-your-mac-running-smoothly-with-onyx/)). The processor uses less than 10 percent of its capacity. I've run First Aid on the disk and tried a bunch of different things to see what the problem is and I cannot for the life of me figure out why it has slown down in the past year. It's even slow using network-less apps (like Excel). I'm running the latest OS X, El Capitan. The only thing I can think of is that perhaps there is an application that is hogging up the HD by writing and deleting or something like that.

Any ideas?

Comment: What specifically is slow? Opening applications? File operations? Number crunching?

Comment: @D34DM347 Opening applications, using them, everything just lags as if the processor was bogged down, but it isn't.